# Why Are Core Graphics Lines Not Aligned?

Tags: ios, swift, rotation, swift2, core-graphics

Quick question: This code should produce (among others) 4 lines that are perpendicular to each other. However, when run, the lines are all off by a small amount.

```
for i in 0..<60 {
    CGContextSaveGState(ctx)
    CGContextTranslateCTM(ctx, rect.width / 2, rect.height / 2)
    CGContextRotateCTM(ctx, CGFloat(6.0 * Double(i) * M_PI / 180))
    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(ctx, UIColor.grayColor().CGColor)
    CGContextMoveToPoint(ctx, 50, 50)
    if (i % 5 == 0) {
        CGContextSetLineWidth(ctx, 3.0)
        CGContextAddLineToPoint(ctx, 30, 30)

    }
    else {
        CGContextSetLineWidth(ctx, 2.0)
        CGContextAddLineToPoint(ctx, 40, 40)
    }
    CGContextStrokePath(ctx)
    CGContextRestoreGState(ctx)
}
```

Still learnings Core Graphics, so sorry if this is simple.

Regards, Brandon

EDIT 1:

Here is what I am getting:

[image: Misaligned Clock Tick Marks]

Comment: Perhaps you should update your question with a small image of what you are getting and perhaps add a small image showing what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I am assuming it correctly, you want to draw ticks that look like ticks on a watch face.

If you let it draw only one iteration, e.g.

```
for i in 0..<1
```

You will see that the first tick starts at some angle. This is happening because you are drawing line from (x=50, y=50) to (x=30, y=30)

Try changing it to (x=50, y=0)(x=30, y=0)

```
for i in 0..<60 {
    CGContextSaveGState(ctx)
    CGContextTranslateCTM(ctx, rect.width / 2, rect.height / 2)
    CGContextRotateCTM(ctx, CGFloat(6.0 * Double(i) * M_PI / 180))
    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(ctx, UIColor.grayColor().CGColor)
    CGContextMoveToPoint(ctx, 50, 0) // <-- changed here
    if (i % 5 == 0) {
        CGContextSetLineWidth(ctx, 3.0)
        CGContextAddLineToPoint(ctx, 30, 0) // <-- changed here

    }
    else {
        CGContextSetLineWidth(ctx, 2.0)
        CGContextAddLineToPoint(ctx, 40, 0) // <-- changed here
    }
    CGContextStrokePath(ctx)
    CGContextRestoreGState(ctx)
}
```

Result

[image]

Comment: First, I can't believe I didn't check that, thank you. Second, yes, but to fit inside the rest of my view, I must have CGContextMoveToPoint(ctx, 50, 50). Which causes the lines to bend in odd ways. Why is this?

Comment: @BrandonBradley I don't understand why you need to move the start point to CGContextMoveToPoint(ctx, 50, 50)? If you do so your line will be (50,50)->(30,0) and will be angled. If you want to move the whole image by some offset then just before the 'for i in 0..<60' line you can add         `CGContextTranslateCTM(ctx, 150, 50)`

Comment: To get the lines against the black circle (see picture) I must use that. Otherwise the ticks appear inside the circle, but not against it.

Comment: @BrandonBradley  Ah.. I think I understand it now.  When I changed (50,50) to (50,0) I effectively changed the length of the lines. You need to recompute the points. Do you know what is the radius of your circle? My guess it is around 70 ('sqrt(50^2 + 50^2)=70.71'). Try to adjust your point positions to something like (70.71,0), (42.42, 0), (56.56, 0) instead of (50,0), (30,0) and (40, 0) respectively.

Comment: I'm not sure why that math works, I'll be sure to look into it, but yes, that works, thanks for all of your help.